# How to implement a function which receives a string and replaces all `"` symbols with `'` and vise versa?

Tags: python, string, replace, character

```
str = input("Something: ")


modified_str = ''


for char in range(0, len(str)):
    # checking if the character at char index is equivalent to 'a'
    if(str[char] == '"'):
        # append $ to modified string
        modified_str += "'"
    elif(str[char] == "'"):
        modified_str == '"'
    else:
        # append original string character
        modified_str += str[char]

print("Modified string : ")
print(modified_str)
```

My output result was:
Something: dd"""ddd'''ddd
Modified string :
dd'''dddddd - but why it doesn't replace ' character

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate

Comment: `modified_str == '"'` looks like a typo for `modified_str += '"'`.

Answer (score 1):

As chepner already mentioned you need to use `+=` instead of `==` in your `elif` branch.

---

You can also **shorten** the code and implement a slightly different, more pythonic logic:

1. Find the indices of `"`
2. Replace all `'` with `"`
3. Set all characters at indices found in the first step to `'`

```py
input = "'test' it or test \"this\""

tmp_idx = [pos for pos, char in enumerate(input) if char == "'"]

result = list(input.replace("\"", "'"))
for idx in tmp_idx:
    result[idx] = "\""
result = "".join(result)

print(result)
```

This performs the replacement you are looking for:

Input: `'test' it or test "this"`

Output: `"test" it or test 'this'`

Answer (score 0):

This would best be solved with [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).

You can create a translation table with [str.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) which allows you to define it in a few different ways. The most readable in your case is probably to use a dict mapping each char to its translation:

```
conversion_table = str.maketrans({'"':"'", "'":'"'})
```

You just need to use the `translate` method of the string you want to convert with this table as argument:

```
print('I\'m getting "converted"'.translate(conversion_table))

# I"m getting 'converted'
```